# Improve Python SKLearn CrossValidation Ouput

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I using the below to get output of estimator.

Is there a faster way to cross validate using scores?

```
for clfx, label in zip([clf0], ['Random Forest']):
        scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clfx, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
        print "Accuracy : %0.3f (+/- %0.2f) [%s]" % (scores.mean(), scores.std(), label) 
        scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clfx, X, y, cv=5, scoring='precision')
        print "Precision: %0.3f (+/- %0.2f) [%s] " % (scores.mean(), scores.std(), label) 
        scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clfx, X, y, cv=5, scoring='recall')
        print "Recall   : %0.3f (+/- %0.2f) [%s] \n" % (scores.mean(), scores.std(), label)
```

Output:

```
Accuracy : 0.82 (+/- 0.00) [Random Forest]
Precision: 0.50 (+/- 0.02) [Random Forest] 
Recall   : 0.13 (+/- 0.01) [Random Forest]
```

Is this overkill and I should be using the confusion matrix from one run?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you want to combine metrics, I think you'll have to "manually" run the cross-validation iterations:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, accuracy_score, recall_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold

all_scores = {'precision':[], 'recall':[], 'accuracy': []}
for train, test in KFold(n = len(X)):
    clfx.fit(X[train, :],y[train])
    y_pred = clfx.predict(X[test])
    all_scores['precision'] += precision_score(y_pred, y[test])
    all_scores['accuracy'] += accuracy_score(y_pred, y[test])
    all_scores['recall'] += recall_score(y_pred, y[test])

scores = all_scores['accuracy']
print ("Accuracy : %0.3f (+/- %0.2f) [%s]" % (np.mean(scores), np.std(scores), label))
scores = all_scores['precision']
print ("Precision: %0.3f (+/- %0.2f) [%s] " % (np.mean(scores), np.std(scores), label)) 
scores = all_scores['recall']
print ("Recall   : %0.3f (+/- %0.2f) [%s] \n" % (np.mean(scores), np.std(scores), label))
```

If you want you could also use `multiprocess` to parallelize this (that's one of the main advantages of using the scikit-learn cross-validation functions):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def score(cv_split, clfx=clfx, X=X, y=y):
    train, test = cv_split
    clfx.fit(X[train, :],y[train])
    y_pred = clfx.predict(X[test])
    all_scores = {}
    all_scores['precision'] = precision_score(y_pred, y[test])
    all_scores['accuracy'] = accuracy_score(y_pred, y[test])
    all_scores['recall'] = recall_score(y_pred, y[test])
    return all_scores

p = Pool(6)
scores_by_run = p.map(score, KFold(len(X)))
all_scores = {k:[d[k] for d in scores_by_run] for k in scores_by_run[0].keys()}
```

Comment: sure, i've rewritten to use multiprocessing

Comment: I am confused by code. Can you please leave single process ans and include multi-process ans. I cant figure out how to use something like :   zip([clf0], ['Random Forest']) for clfx.. I cant see entry point.

Comment: for the loop you'd do `for clfx, label in zip (...): scores_by_run = p.map(score(clfx) ... ) ; all_scores = ... ; print ...`

Comment: Can include above in ans, not the comments.thks